# How do I obtain the shortest random sequence such that it encodes all possible transitions from one element to another?

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, sequence

I am designing an experiment where participants will be prompted a random sequence of actions, and I will be recording data through out the experiment. My intention is to capture every possible transition from one action to another using the shortest sequence possible. Say that there are `N` possible actions, I am searching for an algorithm that can generate a set of random sequences with the following properties:

- Sliding through each sequence, consecutive two elements represents a transition from one action to another. Therefore, except for the start and end of the sequence, every element will serve as the end of one transition and also the start of the next transition. From what I observe using small examples, this approach appears to produce the shortest sequence while covering all transitions.
- Code implementing the algorithm must return all such valid shortest sequences.
- Cannot have two consecutive elements be the same (i.e. self transitions are not allowed).
- Must use basic functions available in Python and MATLAB, so I cannot use modules/libraries that maybe available in Python but not in MATLAB (or vice-versa).

As an example, say I have 3 actions: `{A, B, C}`. One of the expected sequences this algorithm should produce is: `ABCBACA`. Sliding through this sequence, taking 2 elements at a time, I get `{AB, BC, CB, BA, AC, CA}`. As expected, this covers all 6 transitions that is possible using a sequence of length 7. The sequence has no two consecutive elements that are the same. Another valid sequence that this algorithm might produce is: `ACABCBA`. Sliding through this sequence taking 2 elements at a time, I get `{AC, CA, AB, BC, CB, BA}`, thus covering all transitions, with no two consecutive elements being the same.

I worked out both examples using a pen and paper, but I am having trouble seeing a pattern, particularly for `N >3`. How do I proceed from here?

It appears that a sequence of length `N*(N-1) + 1` would be the shortest sequence in my case, which I think makes sense. I also observed that the start and end of such sequences are the same (i.e. if we start at `A`, we end at `A`). It almost appears as if this is a circular list instead of a linear list. Is this generally true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this in the future: I came across [De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) which is almost exactly the solution I want to my problem. The Python code referenced in the article works fairly well for my problem. The only modification I needed to make was that in the output string, I needed to ensure that all permutations involving self transitions (e.g. `AA`, `BB`, `CC`, etc.) were collapsed into single symbols (i.e. `A`, `B`, `C`, etc.).

Also, as the Wikipedia page states:

> ... Note that these sequences are understood to "wrap around" in a cycle ...

So this confirms my observation that the sequences always end and start at the same point. Multiple sequences can be obtained by supplying permuted strings to the input (i.e. the inputs `ABC`, `ACB`, `BAC`, etc.) and we get the outputs we are interested in. The output produced by the Python code appears to be always ordered.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking correctly, here's basically what you need to do:

1. Create a *directed* graph with a node per possible transition (so one for AB, one for AC, etc), and add connections from each node to every node that starts with your "end" (so for AB, you'd connect it to BA and BC -- remember, these are unidirectional)
2. Find an arbitrary Hamiltonian cycle of the graph above.

You're done. Problem is, finding a Hamiltonian cycle is an NP-complete problem in the general case. As such, finding an efficient way of doing it for large N might prove challenging, to put it lightly. If you only need it for N of fairly small size, then you can just pick any algorithm that finds Hamiltonian cycles and stick it in.

Hell, you can probably just concatenate random transitions that 1. haven't been used yet and 2. start with whatever the previous transition ended (in other words, traverse the graph described above at random, without ever returning to a node you've already visited), and if you run out of options before using up all transitions, just start over. It would surely find solutions for small N (say, <= 6) reasonably quickly, and clearly it has equal probability of finding any valid solution.

As for your question on whether the solution will always be circular; yes, that is correct. It's pretty clear to see if you think about the fact that in an optimal solution, you will see every single transition exactly once, and also that any "outgoing" transition must be paired with an "incoming" transition of the same action: e.g. if you start with AB, your pool will contain N transitions of the form xA, but only N-1 Ax ones, and as such you will end up being left with a single dangling transition of the form xA that therefore must come last.

It's possible there is some kind of alternative solution that leverages the structure of this specific problem to produce a more efficient solution, but if there is, I'm not seeing it. This problem is basically a slightly smaller scale version of finding the shortest [superpermutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpermutation), though, which isn't currently known to have a more efficient solution.